# iPhone document mousedown event not firing

Tags: javascript

On iPhone 6, it seems that the mousedown event does not fire on document when it is tapped (but fires when its children is tapped due to event propagation).

Is this a bug or by design? Is there any easy workaround?

-- Edit --

It seems to fire for other elements like div and button (but not document).

Answer (score 1):

It is expectable - there is no mouse on iPhone.

For touch devices use events `touchstart` and `touchend`:

```
$(document)
    .on('touchstart', function(e){

    })
    .on('touchend', function(e){

    });
```

You may also want to read [this MDN article on Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

Comment: It fires for other elements but not document.

Comment: @tumber033 That's strange. It should work. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart), `document` is a proper target for `touchstart` event.

Comment: I mean the mousedown event fires for other elements.

Comment: @tumber033 Ok. What if you use `touchstart`?